# Can I pass an executed sql query to a session variable?

Tags: php, session

I want to print out a table from the results of a query. I know I can do that in the php part of my code after I've run the query by echoing a loop through the returned rows of my query.

However, I specifically want to print out the results of the query in the html part of my code because I want to style the table using my personal css stylesheet.

Hence, I decided to use a Session variable to save the results of my query and pass it to the html part of my code. Then I assumed I could just print out the results via the session variable into my own table.

However, the session variable in the html part of the code is not receiving anything from the php part of the code, making me think that is not possible to send an executed SQL statement. Is this accurate?

Also what is the "best practice" way of printing the results of a query into my own customized table (ideally using my own css stylesheet)?

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
session_start();

#errors on for testing
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

#boolean variable: if Contact Seller variable is set
$ContactSellerClicked = (isset($_POST['contactSeller'])); 

#if Contact Seller Button is Clicked and there is a corresponding userID along with that click
if ($ContactSellerClicked && (isset($_POST['user_id'])) ){



        #assign userID data to variable
        $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];

        #sql query using InnerJoin pulling 
        #firstName, LastName, SchoolName, & Email from student table using userID that matches listing
        $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT `fname`, `lname`, `school_name`, `email` FROM `student` INNER JOIN `listing` ON `student`.`user_id` = `listing`.`user_id` WHERE `student`.`user_id` = '$user_id' ";


        #prepare and execute
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();

        $_SESSION['stmt'] = $stmt;
        header("Location: Seller.php");
        return;

        }
?>
```

Here is the relevant html code:

```
    <table border =1 style=width:500px id="table" class="contact">
 <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>School Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
</tr>

<?php

    $stmt = isset($_SESSION['stmt']) ? $_SESSION['stmt'] : null;

    if($stmt != null){
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
            echo "<tr><td>";
            echo($row['fname'] . ' ' . $row['lname'] );
            echo("</td><td>");
            echo($row['school_name']);
            echo("</td><td>");
            echo($row['email']);
            echo("</td>");
            echo("</tr>");
        }
    }

    ?>
</table>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I dont know if its possible, I hope its not. There is always a workaround for that. Why not close the PHP tag, build your table using plain html and just printing out the parts you have to using PHP?

Comment: No you can't. resource datatype can't be stored in session because it can't be serialized

Comment: @ManuelMannhardt That is a good point. I just tried your suggestion - deleting any reference to a session - and printing the data using my original $stmt variable in the php portion of code. However, I receive an "undefined variable" error because I don't pass that variable to the html part of my code.

Comment: What keeps you from passing it? I mean you have to call your template somewhere from your PHP code, just pass the variable right there.

Comment: @MarkBaker Thank you for the answer. Can you advise me on the best practice way to print the results of a query into a customized table, not just a generic table?

Comment: @ManuelMannhardt I think the issue is I have php code then html code then I call additional php code (printing the table) within that html code and the error is that I can't use a variable from the top part of the php code in my "nested" (for a lack of better word) php code. Does that make sense? Are you suggesting that I should be able to call that variable?

Comment: Oh ok, that sounds pretty messy haha. What you always can do is create a function like `get_table_data()` which you include on top of your file and call the function in a foreach loop or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you? Yes.

Should you? Absolutely not.

Storing complicated objects or very deep nested multidimensional arrays in the session is going to absolutely kill your performance. Your model also has absolutely no business echoing html (that is what views are for).

Your controller should be retrieving the results from the model, and passing them to the view. Your underlying problem is that you need to rethink your architecture flow. From what you have written, you are not using classes or even functions, which is why you are having difficulty. Using classes will allow you to maintain a persistent state, which will let you retrieve the data you need on demand. Something like:

```
class Controller {

    //this represents the object that does the query
    private $model;

    //this represents the object that prints the html
    private $view;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->model = new Model();
        $this->view = new View();
    }

    public function getPage() {
        $data = $this->model->getData();
        $this->view->printPage( $data );
    }
```

Then the Model should be something like:

```
class Model {
    public function getData() {
        //assign userID data to variable
        $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];

        //sql query using InnerJoin pulling 
        //firstName, LastName, SchoolName, & Email from student table using userID that matches listing
        $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT `fname`, `lname`, `school_name`, `email` FROM `student` INNER JOIN `listing` ON `student`.`user_id` = `listing`.`user_id` WHERE `student`.`user_id` = '$user_id' ";


        //prepare and execute
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt;
    }
}
```

And your view should be something like:

```
class View {
    public function printPage( $data ) {
        while ($row = $data->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
            echo "<tr><td>";
            echo($row['fname'] . ' ' . $row['lname'] );
            echo("</td><td>");
            echo($row['school_name']);
            echo("</td><td>");
            echo($row['email']);
            echo("</td>");
            echo("</tr>");
        }
    }
```

And then all you have to do to use them is:

```
require_once 'Controller.php';
require_once 'Model.php';
require_once 'View.php';

$controller = new \Controller();
$controller->getPage();
```

This is very simplified, and you have a number of other things you would want to consider. I suggest you look into how to [properly use objects](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) first, and then read up on [MVC in general](https://www.sitepoint.com/the-mvc-pattern-and-php-1/) before you commit a lot of time to this to avoid a great deal of pain. If you do not understand what a model and a view actually are, you are going to hit a wall. If you do not use classes or at least functions, you will very quickly find it impossible to maintain what you are working on also.

In the simplest laymans terms:

Look at your computer, you will see it has three basic visible parts, the keyboard, the tower/laptop, and the screen.

- The keyboard is the controller. It makes all of the decisions (eg: what you actually typed), and does none of the logic, and prints none of the results.
- The tower/laptop (where the board, hard drive, etc are) does all of the logic. It does not do any of the decision making (it only does what it is told to do) or print any of the results.
- The screen is the view. It prints all of the results, and does not do any of the decision making or logic.

That's about the simplest summary you could ask for. An MVC program works exactly the same way.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response and for pointing me in the right direction. I will read the literature regarding using objects.

Comment: Not sure about your computer analogy - which part is the model?

Comment: The internal parts of the computer are the model. They do all of the actual work, but you have to use the keyboard to tell them what you want (which would be the controller)

Comment: And then the screen (the view) shows you what you get.